# JPA Enumeration Query

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA. I have a `Recipe` entity and a `Difficulty` enum with properties, `EASY`, `MEDIUM`, `HARD`.

My `Recipe` class is composed of `Difficulty`, as shown below:

```
@Enumerated(value=EnumType.STRING)
private Difficulty difficulty;
```

My code works as expected, and I am able to save a Recipe with a difficulty.

My question starts here. What if i want to add multiple enums to one db column? e.g so i want a recipe to have lets say two of these difficulties.

Comment: You don't add several informations in a single column. That would break the normalization rules. You create a table which lists the difficulties for each recipe. It would have a column with the ID of the recipe, and a column with the difficulty. So if you have 3, EASY and 3, MEDIUM in that table, it means that the recipe with the ID 3 has the difficultes EASY and MEDIUM. IN JPA, that would be mapped by an ElementCollection or, if you add an third column to hold a primary key for each row, a OneToMany association with an RecipeDifficulty entity. Read the manual for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom `AttributeConverter` :

```
@Convert(converter = DifficultiesConverter::class)
private List<Difficulty> difficulties;


import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class DifficultiesConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<Difficulty>, String> {
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<Difficulty> attribute) {
    // convert List to String, such as [EASY, MEDIUM, ...] to "EASY,MEDIUM,..."
    return ... 
  }

  public List<Difficulty> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    // convert String to List, such as "EASY,MEDIUM,..." to [EASY, MEDIUM, ...]
    return ... 
  }
}
```